# IE9 XmlHttpRequest returns 12019 error instead of HTTP/417 response code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, internet-explorer

I have some error processing for ajax request to WCF service on client side,

```
 self.remove = function (dep, processingResult) {
            var data = { "id": dep };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'my.svc/remove',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                complete: function (e, xhr, settings) {
                    var message = self.getMessage(e.status);                
                    switch (e.status) {
                        case 200:
                            processingResult();
                            break;                  
                        case 417:
                            console.log(e.statusText);
                            radalert(message + e.statusText, null, null, "417");
                            break;
                        default:
                            {
                                console.log(e.statusText);
                                radalert(message, null, null, "bekey");
                            }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

in some case I return error 417, but IE9 getting result with some 12019 error instead. 
all other browsers including IE10 getting correct value.

Why does it happens and how to fix it ?

> 12019 - ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE
>                  The requested operation cannot be carried out because the
>                  handle supplied is not in the correct state.

Looks like return this code is not so good practice. Am I right ?

```
  WebOperationContext ctx;
//....
  ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed;//417
//...
```

Comment: This occured a fair amount on an older version of IE, http://forums.asp.net/t/1126173.aspx. Can you try the steps in the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If clearing the cache doesn't help, it's likely that this is related to how URLMon wraps certain HTTP error status codes; for instance IE9 and below would convert a HTTP/204 response into a bogus 1223 status code (see http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/bugs.asp)

This problem was fixed in IE10 such that the server's response status is correctly returned to the script.