# Ajax call - 12019 Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, error-handling

We have ajax call in our application like below. It will be called for every left menu click. But sometimes we are getting 12019 error. We are unable to find any other error details. Just we are getting 'xhr.status' as 12019.

```
$.ajax({

    type : 'POST',
    url : requestURI,
    cache : false,
    data : formData,
    success : function(data) {
        $('#centerContentModel').html(data);
        ShowLayer();
    },
    error : function (xhr, errorType, thrownError) {
        alert("Status : "+xhr.status+" :: StatusText : " + xhr.statusText +" :: ErrorType : " + errorType);
        window.location.href = "/timeout.jsp";
    }
```

Anyone has any idea on this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593811/ie9-xmlhttprequest-returns-12019-error-instead-of-http-417-response-code

Comment: This link suggests 'using IE10 will fix the problem'. But we are getting this issue in IE 10 also.

Comment: Do you see this behavior on both Chrome and IE?   ( If I understand the question this is a random issue )

Comment: Yeah, but frequency is more in case of IE.

Answer (score 0):

I thnik you hve using same server for another applications on different port number.

Comment: No, we deploy same application on all ports.